# How to install the Skylander USB Driver?

Tags: pc, skylanders

I am trying to use my portal of power on the Skylander Webpage. I have installed the USB driver, but when I plug in the portal, it asks to try to manually install the driver, but the computer can't find the copy I've installed. Does anyone know how to recover from this issue?

Answer (score 2):

There are two drivers, you'll need to install both of them.
Here's the handy [support page](http://support.activision.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/PC-Portal-Driver-Installation) which gives a nice walk-through.
In essence, the game at http://universe.skylanders.com/ will handle most of it for you, you just have to get into the game and follow the prompts.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

You should install both the web driver and the software driver.Software driver for software version,web driver for web. If it's still not working,reinstall. Do not power your portal on when you have metal objects around it.